# Javascript second prompt is not showing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to code a rock paper scissors game where when I hit the new game button in the middle of the screen it prompts the user for two name inputs. I've seen this in action before but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Hopefully this is enough code to figure it out, otherwise I can post more! Thanks in advance.

```
$('#gameController').bind('click', function() {
    if (game.running === false) {
       if ($(this).text() == 'New Game') {
           for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
               do {
                  var player = prompt('Player ' + i + ', enter your name...');
            } while (!player);
            $('#player' + i + 'Name').text(player);
            game.addPlayer(player);
        }
    };
```

Comment: oops, just re-read the code - please don't put `;` after the `}` of an `if` block, it's not required (to be honest, I wouldn't use `prompt` ever either)

Comment: I edited out the `;` after the `if` block, thanks. Any suggestions to alternatives for the `prompt` then? I'm not too concerned that it's ugly at the moment, more worried about functional.

Comment: I tried executing only the for loop with do...while in jsfiddle. It works fine. Which means your error has something to do with `$('#player' + i + 'Name').text(player);` or `game.addPlayer(player);` Do you see any error in console?

Comment: @nightgaunt, I'm seeing an error saying: "game_engine.js:74 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new Player (game_engine.js:74)" repeatedly. This is the code it's referencing: `this.addPlayer = function Player(playerName) {
        if (players.length <= 1) {
            var player = new Player(playerName);
            players.push(player);
            return true;`

Comment: Well, `game.addPlayer(player);` is causing an [eternal genjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Infinite_Tsukuyomi) (endless recursion) I guess. Please take a look at that code. Your prompts are fine.

Comment: Update your question with above code. Answers will come pouring in.

Comment: @nightgaunt, I edited that line a bit and it seemed to fix that problem! Now onto my many others with this project. If you make your comment an answer I'll check it as a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried executing only the for loop with do...while in jsfiddle. It works fine.

Which means your error has something to do with `$('#player' + i + 'Name').text(player);` or `game.addPlayer(player);`

Based on the comments, I suspect an infinite recursion at `game.addPlayer(player);`. Glad that you found your solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `alert()` e.g. `var player = alert('Player ' + i + ', enter your name...');`

Comment: `alert()` does not return anything and you have also misspelled it

Comment: I may not be understanding you. I tried to switch to `alert()` instead of prompt but it didn't do anything but stick up an endless alert.